# Shortcuts like alt + tab and super + L removed?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, 20.04

I upgraded to 20.04 yesterday (from 18.04 LTS)

When switching applications I was used to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to open the application switcher, but that doesn't work anymore (though <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> still works)

I would also use <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to lock screen, but that doesn't work anymore either.

Is there a way to get those back?